# Rotating Card Animation Glitching

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I am trying to make a rotating card animation. However, whenever I use a few `position: absolute` elements inside one of the sides the animation becomes glitchy and the front side is visible through the back. So far it's been manageable on chrome, but on Safari it's really hard to get my design working without this bug. Below is some code that is glitching on both browsers, please advise what the issue is.

```js
var isLeft = true;
var x = document.getElementById("card");

setInterval(function() {

  if (isLeft) {
    x.style.transform = 'rotateY(360deg)';
  }
  else {
    x.style.transform = 'rotateY(0deg)';
  }
  isLeft = !isLeft;
  
},5000);
```

```css
.scene {
  width:480px;
  height:480px;
  perspective: 35em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
}

.card {
  width:220px;
  height:380px;
  left: 130px;
  top: 50px;
  position:absolute;
  transition: transform 4s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.face {
  border-radius: 10px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  
  color:#FFF;
/*   line-height:15em;
 text-align:center;*/
  position:absolute;
  
  backface-visibility:hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.front {
    position:absolute;
background-color:white;
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
}

.back {
    position:absolute;
  background-color:white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="scene" id="scene">
  <div class="card" id="card">
    <div class="face front">

      <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: purple; position: absolute;"></div>
      <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red; position: absolute;"></div>

      <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; background-color: green; position: absolute;"></div>
      <div style="width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: blue; position: absolute;"></div>

    </div>
    <div class="face back">

      <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; color: white;">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add `z-index: 1;` into `.face` class:

```js
var isLeft = true;
var x = document.getElementById("card");

setInterval(function() {

  if (isLeft) {
    x.style.transform = 'rotateY(360deg)';
  }
  else {
    x.style.transform = 'rotateY(0deg)';
  }
  isLeft = !isLeft;
  
},5000);
```

```css
.scene {
  width:480px;
  height:480px;
  perspective: 35em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
}

.card {
  width:220px;
  height:380px;
  left: 130px;
  top: 50px;
  position:absolute;
  transition: transform 4s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.face {
  border-radius: 10px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  
  color:#FFF;
/*   line-height:15em;
 text-align:center;*/
  position:absolute;
  
  backface-visibility:hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

  z-index: 1; /* works in MS Edge */
}

.front {
    position:absolute;
background-color:white;
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
}

.back {
    position:absolute;
  background-color:white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="scene" id="scene">
  <div class="card" id="card">
    <div class="face front">

      <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: purple; position: absolute;"></div>
      <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red; position: absolute;"></div>

      <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; background-color: green; position: absolute;"></div>
      <div style="width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: blue; position: absolute;"></div>

    </div>
    <div class="face back">

      <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; color: white;">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```